# How to get the all values which have same reference number as an object in json with ios, objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

this is part of my json response in the web service.

```
- Books :[
 -{
     RfNo:"1",
     SegOrd:"1",
     LegNo:"1",
     Title:"wild elephants",
     Author:"Dr.Vijitha Perera",
     Country:"srilanka",
     Price:"$8.99"

  },
   -{
     RfNo:"1",
     SegOrd:"2",
     LegNo:"1",
     Title:"butterfly guide",
     Author:"Dr.Graham fox",
     Country:"united kingdom",
     Price:"$27.99"

  },
   -{
     RfNo:"1",
     SegOrd:"3",
     LegNo:"2",
     Title:"Beautiful birds",
     Author:"prof.saranath kotagama",
     Country:"India",
     Price:"$13.99"

  },
   -{
     RfNo:"1",
     SegOrd:"2",
     LegNo:"1",
     Title:"Nature life",
     Author:"prof.adam jules",
     Country:"USA",
     Price:"$22.99"

  },
   -{
     RfNo:"2",
     SegOrd:"1",
     LegNo:"1",
     Title:"Travel in japan",
     Author:"Mr.yon hoan",
     Country:"japan",
     Price:"$5.99"

  },
    -{
     RfNo:"2",
     SegOrd:"2",
     LegNo:"1",
     Title:"Journey To New York",
     Author:"Mr.Ben carlos",
     Country:"USA",
     Price:"$19.99"

  },
    -{
     RfNo:"2",
     SegOrd:"3",
     LegNo:"2",
     Title:"Life of Canada",
     Author:"Dr.aron parker",
     Country:"Canada",
     Price:"$11.99"

  },
```

I can get these data to a `NSMutableArray` successfully.but now what I want is to get the all data into an arrya which it's `RfNo:"1"`, without others.that means I don't want `RfNo:"2"`, all the data with only `RfNo:"1"`.how can I do that.I took this `Books` into an arrat like this from the response.

```
NSDictionary *allResults = (NSDictionary *)resopnonse;//there isn't only the `Books` that is why I used Dictionary.

NSArray *books = [allResults objectForKey:@"Books"];
for(NSDictionary *all in books)
 {
   //so I want only the data which it's `RefNO:"1"`
 }
```

how can I do that.hope your help.

Comment: Get the `RfNo` value from `all`. If it's `1`, add it to the array. Is that actually your question? Seems too simple to be what you are asking.

Comment: so how can I get the `first` and `last` element which it's `RefNo:"1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use NSPredicate for this.

```
NSArray *bookArray = allResults[@"Books"];

if (!bookArray) return;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"RfNo == 1"];

NSArray *filteredArray = [bookArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This will get you an array of books with RfNo = 1

First Object: `filteredArray[0]`

Last Object: `[filteredArray lastObject]`

Comment: it didn't work for me.when I see with a break point in `bookArray` there are values with 'RfNo = 1' like this ` RfNo = 1;
    SegOrd = 1;`, but then `filteredArray` shows `0` objects.

Comment: Maybe the datatypes differ? If RfNo is an NSNumber try: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"RfNo == %@", @(1)];

Comment: found the error, it should be like this. `NSString *one = @"1";
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"RfNo==%@",one];`, anyway thanx.